# postfix/sendmail: fatal: execvp /usr/sbin/postdrop: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, email, postfix

My server recently crashed and when it came online again I had a number of weird issues popping up. Mostly around ISPConfig.

I've resolved most of the issues but I cannot seem to be able to find the problem with this one.

Whenever we use the "Send copy to" function within the email accounts it doesn't work anymore. It used to work and we did not do any recent updates.

The following errors are in the log file.

```
sendmail[67546]: fatal: execvp /usr/sbin/postdrop: No such file or directory
postfix/sendmail[67545]: fatal: email@mail.com(5000): unable to execute /usr/sbin/postdrop -r: Success
dovecot: lda(rcpemail@mail.com): Error: Sendmail process terminated abnormally, exit status 75
dovecot: lda(rcpemail@mail.com): Error: sieve: msgid=<005701d35ec6$a2a11e80$e7e35b80$@mail.com>: failed to redirect message to <copytoemail@mail.com> (refer to server log for more information)
```

> ISPConfig version: 3.0.5.4p8
>
> Operating system:  SuSE Linux 13.2
>
> Postfix version 2.11.3

I've tried all the other suggestion on stackoverflow semi related to this but nothing helped.

My postdrop and postqueue is under /usr/sbin/ within the maildrop group.

I had a look at the permissions and everything seems fine, I've also restarted all the services.

Please provide full command as I'm not a Linux guru (yet)

Output as requested:

```
file /usr/sbin/postdrop
/usr/sbin/postdrop: setgid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.0.0, BuildID[sha1]=55fb6e550abece72ccb01fb94213418d3ce75c72, stripped

ls -la /usr/sbin/postdrop
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root maildrop 15008 Feb 11  2015 /usr/sbin/postdrop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably there is a conflict with apparmor. May there ist no profile activated for postdrop. Just stop apparmor by

```
service apparmor stop
```

and check if it works.
If apparmor caused the error just have a look at the subdirectories of apparmor at:

```
/usr/share/apparmor
```

Copy the postdrop profile to

```
/etc/apparmor.d/
```

and restart the apparmor service:

```
service apparmor start
```

Check if apparmor is running and you don't have any problems with postdrop.

```
service apparmor status
```